# DB2 simple date comparison

Tags: sql, date, db2

I have two column with date type in table.

Now my objective is to extract all rows where this two column having different value.
Something as below:

```
Select * from tableA where dateColA != dateColB;
```

But I get `SQL0181 Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid`

Comment: can you provide some sample data and your table format etc

Comment: What platform?  I've seen this on DB2 for i when the table is defined with DDS instead of SQL DDL.  A table defined with DDS allows invalid data to be written.

Comment: I suspect one of the columns, likely `dateColB` is not really a `DATE`.

Comment: They are both DATE. It works if using greater or lesser sign '<' or '>' but not working for '!='